# Iphone - Default implementation of numberOfSectionsInTableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm creating a new subclass of UITableViewController, and with it the below default
implementation.
It doesn't compile , cause clearly there is no variable called "number of sections",
what's going on here ?
The error is : "expected expression before '<' token"

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return number of sections;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return <#number of rows in section#>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings `number of sections` and `<#number of rows in section#>` need to be actual integers, corresponding with the number of sections and rows in your data source.

For example, if you have an array of five objects that you want to represent with a table view, and you want them all to go into one section, you need to return `1` from `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `5` from `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

You may want to read Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) to get some familiarity with how table views work, before writing any code.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I just assumed that auto generated implementation should always compile.
Guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: the `<#` and `#>` markers are what tells Xcode to put in those blue placeholder tokens. If you're creating a code snippet for Xcode, anything you put between `<#` and `#>` will behave the same way. When you're writing your actual code you're expected to fill in the correct values, as you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

The default Return Value is 1.
[Check it in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView%3a)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Is a required method